# perl style regex mysqldump column definition

Tags: php, sql, regex, parsing, mysql

I'm trying to fix a bug in [php-mysql-diff](https://github.com/camcima/php-mysql-diff) in regards to the parsing of mysqldump column definitions.

The tools parses correctly lines such as this:

```
`version_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`ucm_item_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`ucm_type_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`version_note` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Optional version name',
```

However fails on lines where there is a ;(semicolon) or /(slash) in the comments

```
`keep_forever` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0=auto delete; 1=keep',
```

The original partial regex is

```
'\((?<tableDefinition>[^;\/]+)\)';
```

see [RegExPattern.php](https://github.com/camcima/php-mysql-diff/blob/master/src/RegExpPattern.php):35, which I understand as "anything that is not a ; or a /"

I want to expand this to:"anything that is not a ; or a /, unless it is inside a pair of ' " (single tick)

I have tried to express this like this:

```
([^;\/]+(COMMENT\s\'[^\']+\')?)+[^;\/]*?
```

which can be explained as "repeat |no ; or /| followed by an optional DDL COMMENT at least one times followed by an optional set of |no ; or /|"

However, even though I tried many similar variations, I can't get any of these to parse the columns above

On top of this, the comment may also contain single quotes as "''" (two single quotes). I have applied this before as

```
\'([^\']+|\'\'))\'
```

(see [commit](https://github.com/camcima/php-mysql-diff/pull/5/commits/d652f483cf1f25c7886864800fb315f03b2d11e4)) 
and this would need to be integrated into the answer somehow as well

Reference: Original code to match table and columns:

```
/**
 * @return string
 */
public static function tables()
{
    $pattern = '/(?<creationScript>CREATE\s+TABLE\s+`(?<tableName>\S+)`\s+';
    $pattern .= '\((?<tableDefinition>[^;\/]+)\)';
    $pattern .= '(?:\s+ENGINE=(?<engine>[^;\s]+))?\s*';
    $pattern .= '(?:AUTO_INCREMENT=(?<autoIncrement>\d+))?\s*';
    $pattern .= '(?:DEFAULT CHARSET=(?<defaultCharset>[^;\s]+))?\s*)';
    $pattern .= '(?:COLLATE=.+?)?\s*';
    $pattern .= '(?:\/\*.+?\*\/)?\s*';
    $pattern .= ';/';
    $pattern .= 's'; // modifier
    return $pattern;
}
/**
 * @return string
 */
public static function column()
{
    $pattern = '/\s*';
    $pattern .= '`(?<columnName>\S+?)`\s+';
    $pattern .= sprintf('(?<columnType>%s)\s*', implode('|', self::$columnTypeRegExps));
    $pattern .= '(?:CHARACTER SET\s+(?<characterSet>\S+))?\s*';
    $pattern .= '(?:COLLATE\s+(?<collate>\S+))?\s*';
    $pattern .= '(?<nullable>NULL|NOT NULL)?\s*';
    $pattern .= '(?<autoIncrement>AUTO_INCREMENT)?\s*';
    $pattern .= '(?:DEFAULT (?<defaultValue>\S+|\'[^\']+\'))?\s*';
    $pattern .= '(?:ON UPDATE (?<onUpdateValue>\S+))?\s*';
    $pattern .= '(?:COMMENT \'(?<comment>[^\']+)\')?\s*';
    $pattern .= '(?:,|$)/';
    return $pattern;
}
```

Comment: And what exactly to you want to get as a result? Do you need the column names? Some `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` mechanism comes to my mind. To get only the column names, [`(?P<column>[^\`]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/tK0jG5/1) works pretty well (mind the `\`` which is considered code in Stackoverflow).

Comment: The tool simply needs each line as a result in preg_match_all for further parsing. As a result of this question I'm looking to simply match the offending line.
I don't want to rewrite the library

Comment: I have added the regular expressions already in use to match table and columns. I'm looking to fix the part of the table regex that matches the column-definitions as a whole

Comment: Do you also need to cater for the corner cases like empty comment strings and juxtaposed string literals ?

Comment: I suppose it wouldn't hurt. I found this tool today and the author and I would sure appreciate any improvements

Comment: You have some potential issues in `$columnTypeRegExps`: `'enum\(.+\)'` and `'set\(.+\)',` Perhaps, you need to change to `'enum\([^()]+\)',  'set\([^()]+\)',`

Comment: @Wiktor, would you mind a pull request on original authors github project? Don't want to sidetrack the question too much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to cater for comments expressly:

Modification of comment pattern:

```
(COMMENT\s\'[^\']+((\'\')+[^\']*)*\')?
```

Modification of tableDefinition pattern:

```
\((?<tableDefinition>([^;\/]+?(.COMMENT.'[^']+(('')[^']*)*'(?!=')))+.*?|[^;\/]+?)\)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I don't recognise how &comment will work, should I just paste this regex line and try?

Comment: There's an error in your expression, it should read: `'\((?<tableDefinition>[^;\/]+(&comment[^;\/]+)*)\)';` (mind the opening parenthesis after `tableDefinition`).

Comment: I fell victim to the subtle differences between perl and php regexen. @Jan thanks; correcting

Comment: It seems logical to me, but somehow fails, mind to look at this in a chat?

Comment: just looking myself. Pinging 10 comments forwards and backwards will recommend one